# Move file after some process in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

File must be moved after successful transaction 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please go through this link on how to ask [minimal, complete questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welocme!!!It is really easy in mule, just the direct way. My question is are you using File component ot FTP or SFTP. It will be helpful if your question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/file-connector, there you find "Move to Pattern" and "Move to Directory".

The file is moved when close() is called on the stream (don't forget to switch streaming on).

You will need two small Java classes:

1. The first has to replace the "byte array to String" and reads the stream to a String (whithout closing the stream). Apache commons has methods for this purpose.
2. The second (behind your transactional, executed only when transaction was successfull) has to close to stream.

Store the stream in a flow variable, so you can return the String in the payload.

Bye the way: When you read the stream into the String, us the correct encoding.